# Android 5.0 Gapps Flashes in Android 6.0 Genymotion

Tags: google, genymotion

I just recently installed Genymotion and need to install Google Apps. Now that I don't have 6.0 Gapps, I tried to experiment by flashing 5.0 Gapps in Genymotion and it worked. Nothing is wrong. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update google apps through play store and run play games app by google. If it works then great. No problem will be shown in future if you can run latest google play games app successfully.